# Merging dataframes on differently-named columns in pandas while only keeping a subset of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets and I need to merge over only specific columns but none of the fields have the same name.

DF1

```
 Name    ID       Job_Type       Emp_Type      
 Adam    101      Full-Time      Employee
 Ben     102      Part-Time      Contractor 
 Cathy   103      Part-Time      Employee 
 Doug    104      Full-Time      Contractor   
 Emily   105      Full-Time      Employee
```

DF2

```
 hiring_manager_id     hire_type      hiring_status     hiring_phase      name_of_emp
         101           Employee          Pending         Requested           NaN
         101           Employee          Approved        Hired               Sam 
         105           Contractor        Approved        Approved            NaN     
         113           Employee          Approved        Hired               Gabe
         119           Contractor        Pending         Interviewing        NaN
```

I would like to take specific columns and add them to `df1` like so:

```
Name    ID    Job_Type    Emp_Type   hire_type    hiring_status   hiring_phase  
Adam    101   Full-Time   Employee    Employee      Pending         Requested  
Adam    101   Full-Time   Employee    Contractor    Approved        Hired 
Ben     102   Part-Time   Contractor  NaN           NaN             NaN 
Cathy   103   Part-Time   Employee    NaN           NaN             NaN 
Doug    104   Full-Time   Contractor  NaN           NaN             NaN 
Emily   105   Full-Time   Employee    Contractor    Approved        Hired
```

I tried

```py
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID','hire_type','hiring_status','hiring_phase']], on = 'ID', how= 'left')
```

This caused an error when I tried it.

Any Suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `df2` doesn't have `ID` column, change it to `hiring_manager_id`. Then use `left_on=` and `right_on=` parameters:

```py
df1 = pd.merge(
    df1, df2[["hiring_manager_id", "hire_type", "hiring_status", "hiring_phase"]], left_on="ID", right_on='hiring_manager_id', how="left"
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
    Name   ID   Job_Type    Emp_Type  hiring_manager_id   hire_type hiring_status hiring_phase
0   Adam  101  Full-Time    Employee              101.0    Employee       Pending    Requested
1   Adam  101  Full-Time    Employee              101.0    Employee      Approved        Hired
2    Ben  102  Part-Time  Contractor                NaN         NaN           NaN          NaN
3  Cathy  103  Part-Time    Employee                NaN         NaN           NaN          NaN
4   Doug  104  Full-Time  Contractor                NaN         NaN           NaN          NaN
5  Emily  105  Full-Time    Employee              105.0  Contractor      Approved     Approved
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only keep one `ID` column, you should rename the "hiring_manager_id" column to "ID":

```py
pd.merge(
    df1, 
    df2[["hiring_manager_id", "hire_type", "hiring_status", "hiring_phase"]].rename(columns={"hiring_manager_id":"ID"}), 
    on="ID",
    how="left"
)
```

```
Name    ID    Job_Type    Emp_Type   hire_type    hiring_status   hiring_phase  
Adam    101   Full-Time   Employee    Employee      Pending         Requested  
Adam    101   Full-Time   Employee    Contractor    Approved        Hired 
Ben     102   Part-Time   Contractor  NaN           NaN             NaN 
Cathy   103   Part-Time   Employee    NaN           NaN             NaN 
Doug    104   Full-Time   Contractor  NaN           NaN             NaN 
Emily   105   Full-Time   Employee    Contractor    Approved        Hired
```